# Detectar si la URL es un wordpress

Tags: php, funciones

Para ello hago una consulta a dominio/wp-admin e intento leer el resultado con la siguiente función:

```
function Url_exists( $url = NULL ) {
    if(empty($url)){
        return false;
    }
    $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
    //print_r($headers);
    if(count($headers['Location']) > 1){
        return url_exists(end($headers['Location']));
    }else{
        sscanf($headers[0], 'HTTP/%*d.%*d %d', $httpcode);
        //Aceptar solo respuesta 200 (Ok), 301 (redirección permanente) o 302 (redirección temporal)
        $accepted_response = array(200, 301, 302);
        if( in_array( $httpcode, $accepted_response)) {
            echo 'existe';
            return true;
        } else {
            echo 'no existe';
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Pero a veces me va bien y otras no, no se por que pero siempre que no es wordpreeess el dominio me dice que no es wordpress pero si es wordpress dependiendo de la web me va bien y otras no

¿Alguien me ayuda?
Gracias

Comment: dominio/wp-admin puede ser cambiada por defecto (y en todos los sitios que mantengo yo, no es wp-admin el punto de entrada, a proposito).

Comment: ¿Si una URL es un Wordpress?  ¿Qué significa eso? Me quedé en el título, sin entender...

Comment: necesito saber si un dominio $x="ejemplo.com" tiene un wordpress instalado y la versión

la mayoría de los worpress mantienen wp-admin como acceso al backoffice por eso he pensado en comprobar esta url pero si alguien sabe indicarme una manera mejor, estupendo!!

Comment: Con que hagas esto sabrás si WP está instalado y qué versión es: **`bloginfo('version');`** También puedes usar la variable global de WP: **`global $wp_version;  echo $wp_version;`** Este código funcionará **desde dentro de WP**, por supuesto.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que se refiere a saber desde su programa en php si una url externa tiene instalado un wordpress

Comment: exacto, sin acceso al servidor (tan solo un allamada), desde una web a otra (que puede estar en ese servidor o en otro), lo siento si no me he explicado bien
gracias  por todo!

Comment: Realmente, no existe una forma segura de saber eso desde fuera de Wordpress. Podrás recurrir a varios métodos, pero ninguno te asegurará que el sitio corre actualmente bajo WP. Además, ten en cuenta que hay plugins de seguridad que ofuscan cierta información... de hecho, saber bajo qué CMS corre un sitio y qué versión es el tipo de información que buscan los hackers. No obstante, puedes verificar archivos como `ejemplo.com/readme.html` o `/license.txt`  pero la presencia de esos archivos no significa que necesariamente el sitio corra bajo WP...

Comment: ...puedes también intentar un `cURL` a direcciones como `/wp-admin.php`  o `/wp-login.php` que serían indicativos más claros de que la URL corre **realmente** bajo WP en caso de tener un status diferente de `404` en respuesta. Pero, también hay plugins de seguridad que cambian estas URL por otras precisamente para que hackers no metan las narices donde no deben. Tampoco estoy seguro si una petición `cURL` a esa URL prosperaría... y si lo hace, también imagino que hay plugins que bloquean ese tipo de peticiones por lo mismo, por la seguridad.